# Set subtraction in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

In my Python code I have this class:

```
class _Point2D:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y    

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'point: (' + str(self.x) + ', ' + str(self.y) + ')'
```

And there are two lists, `initialPointsList` and `burnedPointsList`:

```
initialPointsList = []
initialPointsList.append(_Point2D(1, 1))
initialPointsList.append(_Point2D(1, 2))
initialPointsList.append(_Point2D(1, 3))
initialPointsList.append(_Point2D(1, 4))
initialPointsList.append(_Point2D(1, 5))
initialPointsList.append(_Point2D(1, 6))
initialPointsList.append(_Point2D(1, 7))

burnedPointsList = []
burnedPointsList.append(_Point2D(1, 2))
burnedPointsList.append(_Point2D(1, 3))
```

I want to calculate the difference between `initialPointsList` and `burnedPointsList`

I have executed:

```
result = set(initialPointsList) - set(burnedPointsList)
for item in result:
    print item
```

And get the following output:

```
point: (1, 1)
point: (1, 4)
point: (1, 5)
point: (1, 6)
point: (1, 2)
point: (1, 3)
point: (1, 7)
```

But I expected another result, without burned point coordinates:

```
point: (1, 1)
point: (1, 4)
point: (1, 5)
point: (1, 6)
point: (1, 7)
```

What is the best way to do that in Python? What is incorrect with my code ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want this to work correctly, you need to define the [`__eq__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) and [`__hash__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) special methods.  If you define `__eq__()`, it's usually also a good idea to define [`__ne__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__).

`__eq__()` should return `True` if its arguments are equivalent (their x and y values are the same).  `__ne__()` should do the opposite.  It's usually also desirable for `__eq__()` to do type checking, and return false if the "other" value is not of the same type as `self`.

`__hash__()` should return a number.  The number should be the same for two values which compare equal with `__eq__()`, and it's desirable but not strictly required for it to be different for distinct values.  A good implementation is this:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.x, self.y))
```

The tuple hashing algorithm will combine the hash values of its elements in a statistically well-behaved way.  You may sometimes see people recommend bitwise XOR (i.e. `self.x ^ self.y`) here, but that isn't a good idea.  That technique throws away all the bits they have in common, which makes for inferior hashing performance (e.g. it always returns zero if `self.x == self.y`).

Finally, you need to make sure that **hash values don't change after an object has been constructed**.  This is most easily accomplished by converting `self.x` and `self.y` into read-only [properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: cf https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable && https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__

Comment: Why not use a tuple instead of a class?

Comment: @dallen: Presumably OP wants to do `self.x` instead of `self[0]`.  If that is the *only* reason, they should indeed use a `collections.namedtuple` to avoid having to write the class out by hand.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, here would be the `__eq__`, `__ne__`, and `__hash__` methods as mentioned in Kevin's answer.

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return type(self) is type(other) and self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y

def __ne__(self, other):
    return not self.__eq__(other)

def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.x, self.y))
```

I test it by adding these methods to your class and it produces the expected output:

```
point: (1, 5)
point: (1, 6)
point: (1, 1)
point: (1, 4)
point: (1, 7)
```

Comment: You don't want to just test `other`.  I would recommend testing `type(self) is type(other)` since we only want to return equality for objects of exactly the same type (otherwise, you could have `self == other and not other == self`).  Note that `type(None)` is legal and returns a reasonable unique value.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I updated my answer. Plus that's just a good technique, I might have to update some of my own code.